# Message box formatting

Tags: c#, string, formatting, format, messagebox

I need my totals to be in currency format. my code is not letting me output a long sting into a message box. below is what i am trying to output into a message box. how can i format my totals to come out as currency.

```
        MessageBox.Show(cmboCrust.GetItemText(cmboCrust.SelectedItem) + " - " + cmboSize.GetItemText(cmboSize.SelectedItem)
                     + "\nSauce: " + cmboSauce.GetItemText(cmboSauce.SelectedItem) +
                    "\nToppings ($1.50 each): " + topings +
                    "\n\nPizza total: {0:C}" + pizzaTotal +
                    "\n\nDrink selection: " +
                    "\n\t" + sodaTotal + " soda(s)" +
                    "\n\t{0:C}" + waterTotal + " water(s)" +
                    "\nDrink Total: {0:C}" + drinksTotal +
                    "\n\nSpecialty Items: " + specialtyMessage +
                    "\nAmount Due: {0:C}" + billTotal +
                    "\n\n Deliver to: " + txtBxName.Text + ", " + txtBxAddress.Text
                     , "D & G Pizza Express Order");


        string output = string.Format(cmboCrust.GetItemText(cmboCrust.SelectedItem), " - ", cmboSize.GetItemText(cmboSize.SelectedItem),
                     "\nSauce: ", cmboSauce.GetItemText(cmboSauce.SelectedItem),
                    "\nToppings ($1.50 each): ", topings,
                    "\n\nPizza total: {0:C}", pizzaTotal,
                    "\n\nDrink selection: ",
                    "\n\t", sodaTotal, " soda(s)",
                    "\n\t{0:C}", waterTotal, " water(s)",
                    "\nDrink Total: {0:C}", drinksTotal,
                    "\n\nSpecialty Items: ", specialtyMessage,
                    "\nAmount Due: {0:C}", billTotal,
                    "\n\n Deliver to: ", txtBxName.Text, ", ", txtBxAddress.Text);
```

Comment: How about using an approach with String.Format? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: when i tried that i only got 1 line

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: i did the string output that i just added to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example displays currency symbol with two decimal points.

```
billTotal.ToString("C");
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm you can do it this way..

```
            MessageBox.Show(
            String.Format(
                "\r\nSauce: {0} \r\nToppings ($1.50 each): {1} \r\nPizza total: {2:C} \r\nDrinkSection", 1, 2, 3));
```

you get the idea.. just replace 1,2,3 with your variables

EDIT.
String.Format adds readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
billTotal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
billTotal.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You can format according to current culture or in a required culture by using overloaded `ToString()` method.